# 'Later' of 'See you later'

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms, meaning-in-context, context

> See you!
>
> See you later!

Is there any nuance by adding later or not?

Comment: Highly sensitive to context and to the individuals involved, but "see you later" more strongly suggests that a later meeting (perhaps in an hour, a day, a week) is expected, whereas "see you" is more akin to a simple "goodbye" and does not suggest a later meeting except to the extent that two friends are apt to see each other again.

Comment: Only nuance I know of here has to do with alligators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, "see you later" is more specific than only saying "see you."

Generally, adding "later" will make it sound like you do want to meet again, but are unsure when that will happen.

E.g. "Will I see you at the meeting tomorrow? No? Okay, I'll see you later, then."

I could not say this, however, if I was leaving the office and expecting to see my coworker the next day. I would have to say "See you tomorrow," but I would likely abbreviate this and instead say "See you."